choosing file from google picker and sending to backend through Oauth and File ID is safe?
I want to send google drive file pdf file to gcp bucket with complete security measures
I'm currently working on an application where I need to retrieve a file from Google Picker and then send it to Google Cloud Platform (GCP). To achieve this, I've come up with a temporary solution. I plan to download the selected file from Google Picker using an OAuth token and File ID. Once I have the file, I'll send it to our server and then upload it to a GCP bucket.
Before proceeding, I wanted to double-check if this approach is the right practice. Specifically, I'm concerned about security. I want to ensure that the process is safe from potential hackers.
If this method is not advisable, I would greatly appreciate it if you could suggest a better way to retrieve files from Google Picker and securely save them to GCP.
Looking forward to your guidance on this matter.
Thank you.
